# How to input the date from YYYY-MM-DD to DD-MM-YYYY in laravel

Tags: laravel, datetime

Some people know how to change the YYYY-MM-DD format to become DD-MM-YYYY when inputting to the database and how to display it from the database.

**StudentsController.php**

```
    public function store(Request $request)
{
    //
    $students = new Student();

    $students->nis = $request->nis;
    $students->nama = $request->nama;
    $students->jk=$request->jk;
    $students->nama_sekolah = $request->nama_sekolah;
    $students->alamat_sekolah = $request->alamat_sekolah;
    $students->tanggal_mulai = $request->tanggal_mulai;
    $students->tanggal_selesai=$request->tanggal_selesai;
    $students->email=$request->email;
    $students->alamat_siswa=$request->alamat_siswa;
    $students->no_hp=$request->no_hp;
    $students->email_siswa=$request->email_siswa;
    $students->nama_guru=$request->nama_guru;
    $students->save();
    return back()->with('success','Data Berhasil Ditambahkan');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP can parse most date formats automatically, so to parse either format you can just create a `Datetime` or `Carbon` with the date string as the first argument.

Laravel can then automatically transform `Datetime` and `Carbon` instances to the correct format for your database, so you can do something like:

```php
$dateX = new Carbon($request->get('date_attr')

$students = new Student();

// other attributes 

$students->date = $dateX;

$students->save();
return back()->with('success','Data Berhasil Ditambahkan');
```

Comment: What in this section
$ dateX = new Carbon ($ request-> get **('date_attr')**
use table fields that are in my database or only variables.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL expects date to be formatted like YYYY-MM-DD. So while saving data to the database keep it as it is. When you are displaying the date, you can format it as you wish. To do so make your date as a date in your model.

```
class Student extends Model
{
    protected $guarded = [];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be mutated to dates.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $dates = ['date'];
}
```

Now you can format your date attribute anywhere like

```
$student->date->format("d-m-Y")
```

It will give you the date in DD-MM-YYYY format.

Answer (score 0):

In Laravel 5, you can do it using carbon class.

```
\Carbon\Carbon::parse('2019-04-24')->format('d-m-Y');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `strtotime` date format:

```
date("d-m-Y", strtotime($date));
```